# data.map is not a function error when passing diagram data through props

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a progressbar which consumes the data hard-coded in the same file and works just fine:

```
   const progressData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "1",
    percantage: 1,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "2",
    percantage: 25,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "3",
    percantage: 75,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "4",
    percantage: 35,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "5",
    percantage: 70,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
];

const ProgressbarThree = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {progressData.map((progress) => (
        <TrackVisibility once key={progress.id} className="single-progress">
          <Skill progress={progress} />
        </TrackVisibility>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProgressbarThree;
```

I want the component to get it's data through the props of another component instead of using the array on top. So as my first try, I copied the Array in the parents component and passed it as a prop. Now I get my error.

Parent Component:

```
   const progressData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "1",
    percantage: 1,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "2",
    percantage: 25,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "3",
    percantage: 75,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "4",
    percantage: 35,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: "5",
    percantage: 70,
    progressColor:
      "linear-gradient(124deg, var(--color-tertiary), var(--color-primary)",
  },
];
.....
return (
<ProgressbarThree progressData={progressData} />
....
)
```

Progress Bar Component:

```
const ProgressbarThree = (progressData) => {
  return (
    <>
      {progressData.map((progress) => (
        <TrackVisibility once key={progress.id} className="single-progress">
          <Skill progress={progress} />
        </TrackVisibility>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ProgressbarThree;
```

It should be the same data used, but this time I get the error: TypeError: progressData.map is not a function
I know that error occurs when it's not actually an array, but the data should be the same?

Answer (score 1):

You did not destructure the data passed into your component, change this line:

```
const ProgressbarThree = (progressData) => {
```

to this:

```
const ProgressbarThree = ({progressData}) => {
```

Because what is passed to your function is a props object that contains all the props. You just renamed props to progressData in your example.

An alternative way without destructuring would be this:

```
const ProgressbarThree = (props) => {
  props.progressData.map...
```